# Coin count display display different amount - Unity 2D game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mobile, 2d

I'm creating a 2D car game using unity. Basic idea is adding coin count when player collect coins and display collected coin in the end-game menu. In my CoinCount script, in OnTriggerEnter2D I add coin value to current collected coins.But when game over some times its shows correct answer and some times it's add 2 or more values to collected values.

```c#
//CoinCount script
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D colInfo)
{
    int inc = 0;
    if (colInfo.gameObject.CompareTag("Coin"))
    {
        inc = 5;
        coinCount += inc;
        print("coinCount" + coinCount);
        AudioManager.instance.PlaySound("Coin");
    }

    currentBalance += inc;
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("CoinCount", currentBalance);
    PlayerPrefs.Save();
}
```

I tried maintain a public class for manage coins but it will give the same result. As an example if I collect 5 coins with the value of 5, it should display 25 as total coin count. sometimes it's 30 and 35.

```c#
  public class GameScoreManager : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public static int value;
        public Text currentScoreText;

        // Start is called before the first frame update
        void Start()
        {
            value = 0;
        }

        // Update is called once per frame
        void Update()
        {
            currentScoreText.text = "$" + value.ToString();
            print("Game coin count" + value);
        }
    }
```

This is the CoinCount script after I created the GameScoreManager class.

```c#
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D colInfo)
    {
        if (colInfo.gameObject.CompareTag("Coin"))
        {
            GameScoreManager.value += scoreValue;
        }
    }
```

[image]

I attached this script for each coins for destroy it self after hitting the player

```c#
public class DestroyCoin : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject effect;
    //This script destroy the coin
    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D colInfo)
    {
        if (colInfo.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            Instantiate(effect, transform.position, transform.rotation);
            Destroy(gameObject);

        }
    }
}
```

[image: Wrong coin count]
[image: Wrong coin count]
[image: Correct count]

Much appreciate your help

Comment: Just in general: You shouldn't use `PlayerPrefs` to save player progress. How is your first code snippet related to the second one? Are these two different approaches or are you using both?

Comment: I edited the question. I tried the both ways and give the same result.

Comment: Are you sure that `OnTriggerEnter2D` is only called once? Is it possible that the coins are moving or rotating and that sometimes you enter a coin, exit and enter again due to that movement?

Comment: Coins are not rotating and moving. When player hit the coin, its destroy and so no way to enter the same coin again. I added some space between the coins but that also did not worked

Comment: I don't see they destroying of coins.. also does this happen during the game or only as you stated in the game over?

Comment: During the game play I print the coin values. I'll update the question with screen shots. 100 is the correct answer

Comment: It looks like you should set breakpoints and [debug](https://unity3d.com/de/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/debugging-unity-games-visual-studio) your code in order to see where and when the `GameScoreManager.value += scoreValue;` line is called

Comment: Seems like coin hitting more than once. when a slope comes, vehicle's speed get increased and with that speed the vehicle hit the coin. For disable the coin will take some time(say 0.1ms) during that time vehicle hit again. Then counter will hit again. Any idea to prevent that?

Comment: as a general rule: do not make the destruction of your coin at a different place in the code than the adding of it's value to the player's score. That's just bad practise, and screaming for bugs to happen! (even if you think it should technically work) and even if it does work, you should still feel very guilty about doing it because it's just ugly AF.

Comment: score += value; should happen right next to GameObject.Destroy(coin); basta.
I won't even look further into your code to try to find out why the collision happens multiple times, before I see that you link the destruction of a coin directly to it's adding value to the player's score.Hope that helps you fix your issue

Answer (score 1):

I would go about solving such an issue by linking the addition of the coins value to the player's score DIRECTLY to destruction of the coin.

You might think that in the same game frame your coin gets a collision event to self destruct, and your player gets an event to add the coins value to his score.

If you're a guru and you know how the unity engine's internal mechanisms work by heart, be my guest and use that knowledge to write sloppy code that still works. But for a mere mortal like me, good practice can avoid this type of issues... (for example what if the coin's destruction causes no more collision for the player to add a value to the score?)

Use the same collision event to add a value to the player's score and destroy the coin for good, making sure such an event does not occur again. Even set the coin's value to 0 at that moment, just to be doubble-safe.

Answer (score 0):

I manage to solve the problem by identifying the colider. Checked it's attached in the beginning and then disable the collision after the first hit.

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D colInfo)
    {

        int inc = 0;

        //if (colInfo.CompareTag("Coin"))
        if (colInfo.gameObject.CompareTag("Coin") && colInfo.gameObject.GetComponent<CircleCollider2D>().enabled)
        {
            colInfo.gameObject.GetComponent<CircleCollider2D>().enabled = false;
            Destroy(colInfo.gameObject);

            inc = 5;
            coinCount += inc;

            print("coinCount" + coinCount);
            // AudioManager.instance.PlaySound("Coin");
            currentBalance += inc;
        }

        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("CoinCount", currentBalance);
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
    }
```

Thanks and learnt a lot with this

Comment: isn't that basically what I suggested? (when adding inc to the coinCount, destroy coin (in your case disable collider and destroy the gameObject))